# don't restart from beginning when searching text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I looked in the settings but apparently Sublime Text doesn't have an option to disable the restarting from beginning when doing a search.

I want that SB stops at the end of file when he finished searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the Find bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on OS X) there is a button to "wrap" the search:

[image: Don't wrap search]

If the button is not selected (as shown above), then Find will stop at the end of the file, and not "wrap" back to the beginning. This option is also available in the Replace dialog as well.

Comment: unbelievable how I missed that